# New WPF app that uses MVVM and Database First?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvp, ef-database-first

I creating my first WPF application, and the goal of this is to basically be a data entry application for the database for CRUD operations (for example, creating a new customer in a new window, editing a customer, displaying a list of customers, etc).  A database has been created, and I have thus created a Models folder to contain the .edmx file, dbcontext stuff, and partial classes generated from ADO Entity Data Model tool.

EDIT:

My question is, now, how do I go on with MVVM with my ViewModel and Models working together.  All the tutorials I have seen show starting from scratch, and not using existing classes.  For example, all tutorials would show creating a brand new Customer class, vs just going off the partial Customer class that was created for me.

I don't want to start over, so how do I follow these tutorials alongside the classes that were created for me through Entity Framework from  my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVVM does not specify where you start from, or how you deal with databases.

MVVM specifies you must get rid of the horrible code-behind hacks abundant in some useless dinosaur UI frameworks such as winforms and use DataBinding instead.

Therefore, just go ahead with your existing infrastructure, and make sure you don't manipulate or create UI elements in procedural code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  So, I guess in the MVVM scope then, my models folder (containing the automatically generated POCOs) would be my "M" in MVVM?  Are you also saying that no code should be entered in each "Window.xaml.cs" file?

Comment: @user2317150 no business code. Only View-Specific code. Most of the time unless there's a strict need to do so, you don't place anything in the code behind except the default `InitializeComponent()`.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't want to pick one answer because both of you offered a solution/answer, so thanks for suggestion as well.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion there is nothing wrong in Database-first approach, even it's quite good, because you would have general view at project (data side).

I would recommend you to start MVVM approach using Caliburn.Micro framework, it's easy, powerful and really nice.

[Caliburn.Micro - getting started - part 1](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/01/12/caliburn-micro-part-1-getting-started/) - you can find there all 5 parts.

[Caliburn.Micro - framework](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/documentation)

Comment: Thanks.  I will definitely look into Calibrun.Micro.  I've passed by this, but wasn't sure if I should use a framework or just try to create it by hand.

Comment: Frameworks are very useful while using MVVM :-). So go ahead, in the future you could check out another frameworks like MVVM light, Prism etc.

Comment: Using Caliburn.Micro right now.  Thanks.  Didn't want to pick only one answer as the right one, since they both answer my question.

Comment: so "vote up" :D. Btw. you should choose one to mark question as 'accepted' to inform another users, that this question is solved.

Comment: I could not vote up because I do not have enough reputation.  I chose the other because I would told I should not use a framework for right now.  Thanks again for your suggestion, however, and I will try to use it when possible.